# Do not show devices on the left panel

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

I don't want to show the mounted devices on my left panel(launcher, ubuntu 12.04), and I can just run my ubuntu on 2D mode, so the software myunity tell me "Your Ubuntu 12.04 is running in 2D mode. Many features will not be available." That's why I can't change the option of "show devices" to "never".
Could anybody tell me how not to show the devices on launcher with a command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the mounted devices

```
gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/devices_option  --type=int 0
```

You can also show them

```
gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/devices_option  --type=int 1
```